Analyzing change
I have a dataset with three variables, all measured at two time points:
cycling_amount (cycling time in minutes for a given day),
cycling_distance (distance in m from residence to a specific location. The distance changed for many participants from T1 to T2 due to the construction of a cycling tunnel and other infrastructure changes.)
Time (0 for T1, 1 for T2)
My research question is: Is the change in cycling_distance from T1 to T2 associated with a change in cycling_amount between T1 and T2?
One possible way of modelling this could perhaps be to make change scores for both cycling_amount and cycling_distance and then fit a linear regression, adjusting for baseline cycling_amount (at T1):
cycling_change=cycling_amount_T2-cycling_amount_T1 

cycling_distance_change=abs(cycling_distance_T2-cycling_distance_T1)


 lm(cycling_change = cycling_distance_change + cycling_amount_T1, data=df)

Does this look like a reasonable way of doing it, or are there other and more appropriate ways?
I have also wondered whether to do some mixed modelling, for example:
cycling_amount=cycling_distance_change + (1 | subject_ID)

However, I am a bit confused at the moment about how to proceed, so any help is much appreciated!
Best regards, Kjell Vegard

Not sure what results will be used for and how they will be interpreted, but it seems rather trivial that cycling amount in minutes and cycling distance will be directly related, and so will potential changes in these. So your research question doesn't seem very interesting as it stands, and I wonder whether this is really what you are after here.

I am not sure I understand why you take the absolute value of 1 variable? This would mean that if e.g. the amounty of time decreased (negative 1st variable), then the distance increased? (always positive 2nd variable). That does not feel right?
